# Maximum update depth exceeded with useReducer in custom hook but not with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-table, react-table-v7

**Code example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-cherry-z8hn9

I'm using react-table to create a table component that receives a configuration object with options + columns configuration.

I have created 2 components, a `TableInstance` and a `Table`

The `TableInstance` component handles the data and state of the Table and the Table only handles de UI rendering.

I have also created 2 custom hooks that handle state and data in the `TableInstance` component.

Hook 1, called `useTableState`, has a simple reducer that sets the `pageSize` and the current `page`

Hook 2, called `useTableData` makes a query and returns the data plus it also returns the columns configuration that `react-table` needs.

Following the examples in the `react-table` docs, I created 2 `useEffect` hooks (`TableInstance.js` lines 33 and 38) that react when the state from the table changes on pagination, when that happens, I dispatch an action in the `useTableState` reducer that updates the state to set the `pageSize` and `page`.

The problem occurs when I set `manualPagination: false`. I get `Maximum update depth exceeded` because `TableInstance` constantly re-renders. I don't know what causes the re-renders. If instead of using `useReducer` I use `useState` then the error doesn't happen. You can check it our yourself, in the hook `useTableState` I left the `useState` approach commented, if you just comment the dispatchers and uncomment the setState then you will the error dissapear.

Again, the problem is ONLY when using `manualPagination: false`, if I then use `manualPagination: true` controlling the pagination myself then there is no problem. You can also try it yourself changing the configuration in the `tableConfig` file

Would really appreciate some help as I'm a bit lost here , what am I not seeing that causes this issue?

**TLDR**: `useReducer` in combination with react-table pagination causes an infinite loop of re-renders that gets fixed if I change the approach to `useState` instead

**Code example:** https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-cherry-z8hn9

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `column` variable as a dependency in the `useMemo` of `useTableData`. Adding this will fix the issue.

```
const tableColumns = useMemo(() => {
    return buildTableColumns(columns);
  }, [columns]);
```

Here's a fork of your sandbox showing the effect of the change https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-jepsen-657lm

Comment: Not really, the problem is more in the data fetching side. Adding this doesn't solve much. But thanks!

Comment: I  got the maximum depth error when I visited your code sandbox, but the table renders correctly on my end when I made this change. I couldn't switch pages using the carets, although I updated the number of elements per page. It seems you may have a different problem than what you specified.

Comment: What you mention is a problem with codesandbox, you have to manually reload the page with the reload button on the top left of codesancbox window

Comment: I still get the error when I reload in your sandbox if I don't add the dependency.